# Error while installing autoit to robot framework

Tags: python, installation, autoit, robotframework

I am trying to install autoit to robot framework, but got stumped with latest error message.

Currently I have installed (everything as 32-bit):

- Python 2.7.6
- setuptools 1.3.2
- pip 1.4.1
- robot framework 2.8.1
- robot framework-ride 1.2.2
- selenium2library 1.4.0
- wxPython 2.8.12.1 (unicode)
- pywin32 (218.win32-py2.7)

AutoIt I am trying to install is AutoItLibrary-1.1
(http://code.google.com/p/robotframework-autoitlibrary/)

I have it unzipped and in folder in C:\, I am running command line as admin and given command "python setup.py install".

It starts to install autoit but in end runs in weird error message. So far i have not found anything in internet for possible cause nor have found anything to point as reason on my PC.

What it looks like on command line:

```
C:\AutoItLibrary-1.1>python setup.py install
%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\regsvr32.exe /S C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\lib\AutoItX3.dll
python C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\makepy.py C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\lib\AutoItX3.dll
Generating to C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\F8937E53-D444-4E71-9275-35B64210CC3Bx0x1x0.py
Building definitions from type library...
Generating...
Importing module
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib
creating build\lib\AutoItLibrary
copying src\AutoItLibrary\Counter.py -> build\lib\AutoItLibrary
copying src\AutoItLibrary\Logger.py -> build\lib\AutoItLibrary
copying src\AutoItLibrary\__init__.py -> build\lib\AutoItLibrary
running install_lib
copying build\lib\AutoItLibrary\Counter.py -> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary
copying build\lib\AutoItLibrary\Logger.py -> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary
copying build\lib\AutoItLibrary\__init__.py -> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary
byte-compiling C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\Counter.py to Counter.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\Logger.py to Logger.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\__init__.py to __init__.pyc
running install_data
creating K:\
error: could not create 'K:\': The system cannot find the path specified
```

As you can see, that weird creating K:\ error is what is causing this problem. I have tried to install autoit with couple different python & robot framework version sets. Also tried with and without java installed (read somewhere it migth cause trouble). I don't even have any idea why it tries to create K:. At this point I'm welcoming all the help I can get.

Naali

Comment: You know, that `K:\` is the root directory of another disk drive? So it depends on your system whether or not there is a drive with the letter **K**. Is it probably a mapped network device where you ain't got write permissions?

Comment: I should told in first place that I do have network drive at K:. I also tried installing it without that K: drive and K drive mapped to different letter (L), and still received same error message.

Comment: Then obviously there must be any parameter in the function/method/section **install_data** inside the `setup.py` that refers to `K:\\` . Probably in some imported configuration file, but you should find it and replace it with a valid drive letter...

Comment: I tough so too, but I can't find in any of the files/folders related to this about any mention to 'K:\' or file install_data or even mention install_data. That's why I am so stumped at what is causing this problem or how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem  was your environment variable `HOMEDRIVE` is set to `K:`.  If you look on line 88 of setup.py, you will see the `destPath` is set to `HOMEDRIVE:\RobotFramework\Extensions\AutoItLibrary`.  So, just override the environment variable `HOMEDRIVE` to `C:`, it will work.